# Vue CLI - compile CSS files individually from directory of .scss files

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, css-loader, vue-loader

I am using Vue CLI which abstracts away much of the Webpack configuration for running and building the application. This comes with some benefits, but I am at a loss as to how to create specific rules for a directory of `.scss` files.

I would like these files to **not** be extracted into a single `.css` file on build, but to be individually compiled into a themes directory (`./dist/themes`).

I have tried to create a rule in `vue.config.js` to recognise the directory but it does not work:

```
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  configureWebpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ya?ml$/,
        type: 'json', // Required by Webpack v4
        use: 'yaml-loader'
      }
    )
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          import: (url, media, resourcePath) => {

            // Find .scss files in src/assets/themes 
            if (url.includes('./src/assets/themes')) {
              
            }

          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your format in vue.config.js is incorrect. This is how you pass scss options to the loader:

```
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            scss: {
                   // options
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how you configure the output to be how you want it but this should help you. To see what vue.config.js is translated to in terms of webpack you can run `vue inspect`

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll reformulate the question because I don't know how to do this with a standard Webpack configuration.